# How can I put asearch text for the name in this list view?

Tags: java, android, listview, search, full-text-search

I want to search with a text on this list

```
class listAdpter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<Listittem2> listA = new ArrayList<Listittem2>();
        public listAdpter(ArrayList<Listittem2> listA) {
            this.listA = listA;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listA.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listA.get(position).name;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();


        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tahaaaarow, null);
        TextView center = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        TextView location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView15);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
        center.setText(listA.get(position).name);
        location.setText(listA.get(position).city+" - "+listA.get(position).street);

        Picasso.with(CompanytwoDetalies.this).load("http://zaidproject.16mb.com/feedsup/" + listA.get(position).img).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(img);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: what should i do to filter the listview with an edittext,so the user can search

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic adapter